# How to determine the end of an Opus stream?

Tags: audio, voip, pcm, opus

I'm writing a program which is reading a non-continuous stream of Opus packets transmitted via UDP - in other words, I may get 30 seconds of audio, 30 minutes of nothing, and then 2 minutes of audio.

I've been able to use the [official Opus docs](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus_api-1.3.1/index.htmll) to be able to decode, save, and playback the audio, but I haven't been able to find a way to determine that a stream is *complete*. I've seen references to a flag indicating that a stream is complete (e.g. Ogg pages have a flag), but I'm not familiar enough with audio to be sure if what I'm getting is Ogg-encoded or if I should be looking deeper into the actual Opus packet itself.  The [RFC itself](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7845) doesn't seem to help that much either.

For what it's worth, [this](https://github.com/ciribob/DCS-SimpleRadioStandalone) is the program doing the transmitting (and my receiving code is Python.)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Opus packets themselves are stateless audio, and all organization of those packets would occur in the encapsulation/container of them (Ogg, WebM, etc). From what I know, Opus is meant to be a streaming format that does not contain pre-defined durations.

From reading "[How do I get the duration of a .opus file?](https://wiki.xiph.org/OpusFAQ#How_do_I_get_the_duration_of_a_.opus_file.3F)," you could potentially use serial numbers to identify the start of new "logical Ogg bitstreams" and determine the "end" of a bitstream when a new serial number is encountered. "*[Logical bitstreams are identified by a unique serial number](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3533#section-4)*" (Ogg Spec RFC 3533, which parents Ogg Opus Spec RFC 7845).

When using `opusenc` and `opusinfo` to encode Ogg Opus files, you'll see the bitstreams listed with serial numbers:

```sh
$ opusinfo audio-test.opus
Processing file "audio-test.opus"...

New logical stream (#1, serial: 30b7344f): type opus
...
Opus stream 1:
...
Logical stream 1 ended
```

Comment: I'd like to preface this comment with a statement that I'm totally out of my league here and am making educated guesses, not informed statements.  You mention that the packets themselves are stateless but [the docs](https://opus-codec.org/docs/opus_api-1.3.1/group__opus__decoder.html) seem to indicate otherwise: "Opus is a stateful codec with overlapping blocks and as a result Opus packets are not coded independently of each other."  The page you linked is for a file but I'm talking about a stream. Am I missing something? Are serial numbers included in streams as well?

Comment: Ha, I'm severely dyslexic and totally misread/misinterpreted that part. Serial numbers are included in the Ogg bitstream, I don't believe they are in Opus packets themselves. I just updated the answer to show that.

Comment: Also, for an authoritative answer, see [Opus codec - contact](https://opus-codec.org/contact/). They're always very responsive and helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply (both times.)  Since this isn't really an answer (despite being helpful), I've upvoted your response and will reach out to them via IRC.

Comment: no worries, I don't need points/credit. happy to help!  Willing to post the when you find it so others in the community can benefit as well? The email list is also archived/searchable, so email vs IRC may benefit others more too.